# How to send zipped http request?

Tags: java, web-services, zip, http-post

I want to send a zipped request body as a POST http request for a web-service based application. Can anybody please help me how can I send a zipped http request or how can i send a zipped request body as part of POST http request?

**Edit**: *Adding the solution here*

```
HttpURLConnection request = null; 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getFileAsString("TestFile.txt")); 
String fileStr = getFileAsString("TestFile.txt"); 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
client.getState().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(hostip, port), 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")); 
PutMethod post = new PutMethod(url); 
post.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
```

Answer (score 5):

HTTP protocol doesn't support compressed requests (it does support compressed responses being exchanged where the client would announce its ability to handle compressed content). If you want to implement compressed requests, then such a protocol should be established between the client and your web-service that the HTTP payload is always compressed so that on the receiving side, the web service can always decompress and interpret the payload.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue and we can send zipped http post request.Need to use apache HTTPClient for this purpose. Can u please tell me how can I attach a code here for reference

Comment: HttpURLConnection request = null;
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getFileAsString("TestFile.txt"));
   String fileStr = getFileAsString("TestFile.txt");
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(hostip, port),
                     new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
   PutMethod post = new PutMethod(url);
   post.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException,
        IOException {

    HttpURLConnection request = null;
    try {

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getFileAsString("TestFile.txt"));

        String fileStr = getFileAsString("TestFile.txt");

        System.out.println("FileData=" + sb);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          client.getState().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(hostip, portno),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

        PutMethod post = new PutMethod(url);
        post.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        post.setDoAuthentication(true);

        byte b[] = getZippedString(fileStr);;
            InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        post.setRequestBody(bais);
        try {
            int status = client.executeMethod(post);

        } finally {
            // release any connection resources used by the method
            post.releaseConnection();
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a special servlet that decompress and compress the requests and responses

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{

    InputStream zipedStreamRequest = req.getInputStream();
    String unzipJsonStr  = ZipUtil.uncompressWrite(zipedStreamRequest);
    System.out.println("<---- ZIP request <----");
    System.out.println(unzipJsonStr);
    MainHandler handler = new MainHandler();
    String responseJson = handler.handle(unzipJsonStr);
    System.out.println("----> ZIP response ---->");
    System.out.println(responseJson);

    OutputStream responseOutputStream = res.getOutputStream();

    if (responseJson!=null) {
        ZipUtil.compressWrite(responseJson, responseOutputStream);  
    }

}
```

then here is my ziputil class

```
public class ZipUtil {

private static final int NB_BYTE_BLOCK = 1024;

/**
 * compress and write in into out
 * @param in the stream to be ziped
 * @param out the stream where to write
 * @throws IOException if a read or write problem occurs
 */
private static void compressWrite(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{
    DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutput = new DeflaterOutputStream(out);
    int nBytesRead = 1;
    byte[] cur = new byte[NB_BYTE_BLOCK];
    while (nBytesRead>=0){
        nBytesRead = in.read(cur);
        byte[] curResized;
        if (nBytesRead>0){
            if (nBytesRead<NB_BYTE_BLOCK){
                curResized = new byte[nBytesRead];
                System.arraycopy(cur, 0, curResized, 0, nBytesRead);
            } else {
                curResized = cur;
            }
            deflaterOutput.write(curResized);
        }

    }
    deflaterOutput.close();
}

/**
 * compress and write the string content into out
 * @param in a string, compatible with UTF8 encoding
 * @param out an output stream
 */
public static void compressWrite(String in, OutputStream out){
    InputStream streamToZip = null;
    try {
        streamToZip = new ByteArrayInputStream(in.getBytes("UTF-8"));           
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ZipUtil.compressWrite(streamToZip, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * uncompress and write int into out
 * @param in
 * @param out
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static void uncompressWrite(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{
    InflaterInputStream inflaterInputStream = new InflaterInputStream(in);
    int nBytesRead = 1;
    byte[] cur = new byte[NB_BYTE_BLOCK];
    while (nBytesRead>=0){
        nBytesRead = inflaterInputStream.read(cur);
        byte[] curResized;
        if (nBytesRead>0){
            if (0<=nBytesRead && nBytesRead<NB_BYTE_BLOCK){
                curResized = new byte[nBytesRead];
                System.arraycopy(cur, 0, curResized, 0, nBytesRead);
            } else {
                curResized = cur;
            }
            out.write(curResized);
        }
    }

    out.close();
}

/**
 * uncompress and write in into a new string that is returned
 * @param in
 * @return the string represented the unziped input stream
 */
public static String uncompressWrite(InputStream in){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        uncompressWrite(in, bos);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        byte[] byteArr = bos.toByteArray();
        String out = new String(byteArr, "UTF-8");
        return out;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}